# Logging of POST requests, cookies and XID in varnish (varnishncsa)

Tags: logging, varnish, cookies, varnishncsa

I would like to include following information in my varnishncsa logs (I need to relate some issues with specific users).

- content of post requests
- cookie with full content
- XID

After reading https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishncsa.html I am not really sure how I can achieve it.

BTW, I am not able to add the "varnishncsa" tag to the question - someone can add it (with higher reputation? :P).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with the varnish 3.0.3 release:

https://www.varnish-cache.org/releases/varnish-cache-3.0.3
http://lassekarstensen.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/varnishncsa-and-std-log/

[Logging of POST requests, cookies and XID in varnish (varnishncsa)](https://serverfault.com/questions/412549/logging-of-post-requests-cookies-and-xid-in-varnish-varnishncsa)

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to use varnishncsa? Varnishlog (with some extra command line options or shell piping magic) can give you the cookies (and their contents), and the XID, easily. I doubt the full content of the POST requests is available to log.

Comment: :( How I can do it with the varnishlog at least?